# angular 7 app not talking to asp.net web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have developed an angular 7 basic app and asp.net web api. Both these applications are running perfectly fine in isolation. I dont want to host my applications on IIS. I am trying to run both using thier local webserver. The angular app by default on ng serve , uses http://localhost:4200. The webapi uses a different port. My question is how do I make both the applications communicate since they are on different ports. I tried changing the port in the webapi to point to 4200 but when I do ng serve, i get a message saying it is already in use and please use another port. Could somebody help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `ng serve`, you need `--proxy-config` option to communicate to other port. If your .net server is on port 8080, create a `proxy.conf.json` like below:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and run:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

When you access `/api/*` via your Angular app, it bypasses to your .net server.